# Laravel Sqlsrv eloquent query error

Tags: sql-server, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following query generated by laravel:

```
insert into [web_cmdelt] (
    [id], 
    [list_num], 
    [is_main], 
    [published_at], 
    [list_title], 
    [artdes], 
    [unitdes], 
    [unitprix], 
    [detail_qty], 
    [catdes], 
    [souscatdes], 
    [art_origine], 
    [art_label], 
    [art_transport], 
    [art_culture], 
    [art_annexe5], 
    [art_annexe6], 
    [artcateg], 
    [artsouscateg], 
    [hash]
) values (4728, 1004, 1, 2015-02-12 10:33:02.000, COMPANY NAME, AUBERGINE "P"ESP , Kg, 5.80, , LEGUMES, LEGUMES, ESP, , , , , , 1, 7, 1619328673)
```

from this object:

```
object(Ronin\Entities\OrderItem)[230]
  protected 'connection' => string 'webcmd' (length=6)
  protected 'table' => string 'web_cmdelt' (length=10)
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'cmdelt_id' (length=9)
  public 'timestamps' => boolean false
  protected 'fillable' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=20)
      'id' => string '4728' (length=4)
      'list_num' => string '1004' (length=4)
      'is_main' => string '1' (length=1)
      'published_at' => string '2015-02-12 10:33:02.000' (length=23)
      'list_title' => string 'COMPANY NAME' (length=18)
      'artdes' => string 'AUBERGINE "P"ESP ' (length=17)
      'unitdes' => string 'Kg' (length=2)
      'unitprix' => string '5.80' (length=4)
      'detail_qty' => null
      'catdes' => string 'LEGUMES' (length=7)
      'souscatdes' => string 'LEGUMES' (length=7)
      'art_origine' => string 'ESP' (length=3)
      'art_label' => null
      'art_transport' => null
      'art_culture' => null
      'art_annexe5' => null
      'art_annexe6' => null
      'artcateg' => string '1' (length=1)
      'artsouscateg' => string '7' (length=1)
      'hash' => string '1619328673' (length=10)


    ...
```

The problem is that SQL Server raise this error (sql editor error):

```
ErrorCode: -2146232060

[.Net SqlClient Data Provider]
Number: 102, Class: 15, State: 1, Line: 1
ErrorMessage: Incorrect syntax near '10'.
```

I see many problems here:

- the date isn't quoted, so the space between date and time breaks the query
- same for any other string field (why they aren't quoted ??)
- the NULL values are inserted as '' (but without quotes)

Can someone point me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

This raw format should fix the issue.

```
DB::insert("insert into users (id, name) values (1,'Kamaro Lambert')");
```